# Schedule functions from a json configuration file

Tags: node.js, node-schedule

I have a json configuration file that hold a list of default jobs to schedule in my nodeJS app.
The purposer is to schedule (with node-schedule) some functions of my module from this file to manually define its interval.

The problem is that the json file store the function name (`job.name` below) as string ans I need to pass a function to `schedule.scheduleJob`.

I tried with `this[job.name]` and `module[job.name]` but it is the same.

Thanks in advance

```
// ../conf/service
{
    "scheduler": {
        "defaultJobs": [
            { "name": "jobOne", "schedule": "*/1 * * * * *" }, // each second
            { "name": "jobTwo", "schedule": "*/3* * * * *" } // every 3 seconds
        ]
    }
}
```

```js
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const conf = require('../conf/service').scheduler;

let count=0;
function jobOne() {
    console.log(`jobOne n°${count++}`);
}

let count1=0;
function jobTwo() {
    console.log(`jobTwo n°${count1++}`);
}


conf.defaultJobs.forEach(job => {
    schedule.scheduleJob(job.schedule, job.name); // call jobOne and jobTwo
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the trick by storing your functions inside an object:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
const conf = require('../conf/service').scheduler;

let count=0;

function jobOne() {
    console.log(`jobOne n°${count++}`);
}

let count1=0;
function jobTwo() {
    console.log(`jobTwo n°${count1++}`);
}

const jobs = {
    jobOne,
    jobTwo
}

conf.defaultJobs.forEach(job => {
    schedule.scheduleJob(job.schedule, jobs[job.name]); // call jobOne and jobTwo
});
```